# Could anyone help me with this problem? Which is the odd one out?

Tags: odd-one-out

Which is the odd one out from these words? 
Beijing, Helsinki, Paris, Athens, Sydney and Wellington. 
All of them are capitals but I don't know what is the difference.

Comment: There are too many possibilities depending on different criteria. In future puzzles of this type, additional clues should be provided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Sydney is not a capital, Canberra is the capital of Australia.

Answer (score 1):

Or maybe

> Wellington

because in every other city

> were Summer Olympic Games

Answer (score 0):

There are many other possibilities @Mohammed

> Paris : Only word with no "e" or "n"
>
> Athens: Only word starts with a vowel

and so on